# How to loop through and segment a string into an array using a RegExp?

Tags: javascript, regex, iteration, zapier

I use the custom JS code heavily in Zapier. When arrays are imported into this step, Zapier converts it it into a literal string, i.e:

['BigBoatBob, XL-1', 'LittleBoatMike, M-2', 'SunkBoatCheney, XS-9']

turns into:

'BigBoatBob, XL-1,LittleBoatMike, M-2,SunkBoatCheney, XS-9'

I've created a function to parse out the array items (accounting for textual commas) but it seems very, VERY sloppy. Anyone have any suggestions to refine / shorten/ make look more professional? Thanks for helping me to further my abilities :)

```
var array = splitArray('BigBoatBob, XL-1,LittleBoatMike, M-2,SunkBoatCheney, XS-9');

function splitArray(x) {
  const pos = [];
  const POS = [];
  const res = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    if (x[i] == ',') pos.push(i);
  }
  for (i = 0; i < pos.length; i++) {
    let a = x.slice(pos[i]);
    if (!a.startsWith(', ')) POS.push(pos[i]);
  }
  POS.push(x.length);
  POS.unshift(0);
  for (i = 0; i < POS.length - 1; i++) {
      res.push(x.slice(POS[i], POS[i+1]));
  }
  return res.map(x => {
    if (x.startsWith(',')) {
      return x.slice(1);
    } else {
      return x;
    }
  });
}
console.log(array);
```

Comment: *"Zapier converts it it into a literal string"* I suspect something else is doing that, since what you've shown is the default result of converting a JavaScript array of strings into a single string.

Answer (score 0):

**If** you can rely on the spaces after the commas *within* the strings and rely on their **not** being one *between* the strings, you can use `split` with the regular expression `/,(?! )/` which says "a comma **not** followed by a space:"

```js
const str = 'BigBoatBob, XL-1,LittleBoatMike, M-2,SunkBoatCheney, XS-9';
const array = str.split(/,(?! )/);
console.log(array);
```

If you **can't** rely on that but you can rely on the format of the `XL-1` and such, you can do it with an `exec` loop (or with an up-to-date JavaScript engine or a polyfill, with `matchAll`):

```js
const str = 'BigBoatBob, XL-1,LittleBoatMike, M-2,SunkBoatCheney, XS-9';
const array = [];
const rex = /(.*?,\s*[A-Z]{1,2}-\d)\s*,?/g;
let match;
while ((match = rex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    array.push(match[1]);
}
console.log(array);
```

The regular expression `/(.*?,\s*[A-Z]{1,2}-\d)\s*,?/g` means:

- `.*?` any number of any character, non-greedy
- `,` a comma
- `\s*` zero or more whitespace characters
- `[A-Z]{1,2}` one or two letters from the range A-Z
- `-` a dash
- `\d` a single digit (use `\d+` if there can be more than one)
- All of the above is in a capture group
- `,?` an optional comma following it

Comment: I am an idiot. You are my hero!

This is MUCH better ( and shorter ). Thank you!

Comment: @SlavenMan'sGym - I can't upvote a comment where you call yourself an idiot. :-) Glad that helped!

Answer (score 0):

I would use Array.reduce:

```js
var s = 'BigBoatBob, XL-1,LittleBoatMike, M-2,SunkBoatCheney, XS-9'
var result = s.split(',').reduce((acc, curr, i) => {
  if(i % 2 == 0) { acc[i] = curr }
  else { acc[i - 1] += curr }
  return acc
}, []).filter(x => x)
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Shorthand,

```
function splitIt(str) {
return str.split(',').reduce((a,v,i)=>((i % 2 == 0)?a.push(v):a[a.length-1]=a[a.length-1]+","+v,a),[]);
}

// Example

let str = `BigBoatBob, XL-1,LittleBoatMike, M-2,SunkBoatCheney, XS-9`;

console.log(splitIt(str));
```